# How to enable create / insert in a AxGridView in Enterprise Portal (Dynamics AX 2009)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, enterprise-portal

There must be a way to enable creation and insertion of a record from a AxGridView without using the Tunnel and Wizard approach. From what I have found on the Internet so far, the only example is using a Wizard, and I honestly don't find that to be a user friendly approach.

Has anyone tried to enable insertion of records directly from a AxGridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to enter data through AxGridView. Just enable Editing, deleting for that control. And one more thing to make new row - you have to make addditional button - create new line, and code behind:

```
protected void NewLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int editIdx = AxGridView1.EditIndex;      

    try
    {
        // Save the last unsaved line if any
        if (AxGridView1.EditIndex != -1 && AxGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.AxGridView1.UpdateRow(AxGridView1.EditIndex, true); 
        }


        DataSetViewRow dsvr = this.dsv.AddNew();        
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        AxExceptionCategory exceptionCategory;

        if (!AxControlExceptionHandler.TryHandleException(this, ex, out exceptionCategory))
        {
            // Throw the fatal exception
            throw;
        }
        if (exceptionCategory == AxExceptionCategory.NonFatal)
        {
            AxGridView1.EditIndex = editIdx;
        }
    }
}

private DataSetView dsv //get dataset view
    {
        get
        {
            DataSet dataSet = this.AxDataSource1.GetDataSet();
            return dataSet.DataSetViews[this.AxGridView1.DataMember];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. There are a couple of other things I needed to do too. Actually I found the solution in the EPProjTimeSheet.ascx.cs file that comes with Dynamics AX 2009.